# Loading saved data into textvariable Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a sheet that allows a user to a name and age with Tkinter.
The data get's stored into a list that consists of 100 of StringVar()

```
NameInput = []
v1list = []
for i in range(1, 100):
    v1list.append(StringVar())
                NameEntry = Entry(frame, textvariable=v1list[i-1], bg = bg, fg = fg, font = font, width=20).grid(row = i, column = 0, sticky=W)
```

Now I've saved this data as strings in a txt file. Like this

```
Bob 37
```

But the problem is loading it back into the program and making users able to change it.

Later on I use .get() to get the user input.

```
NameList = [var1.get() for var1 in v1list]
```

To get the data from my .txt I'm using

```
for i in range(1, 100):
        if FileLine[i-1] != ('\n'):
            with open('File.txt', 'r') as file:
                FileLine = file.readlines()
                SplitLine = FileLine[i-1].split()
                UserName = SplitLine[0]
                UserAge = SplitLine[1]
```

I'm clueless on how to make it so it properly loads this data into the lists of stringvars without making it fail userinput or the .get().

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid

```
v1list[i-1].set(UserName)
v2list[i-1].set(UserAge)
```

Would work for this.